# Create a modded server with just a few mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm looking to create a modded server, with just a few mods in it, (pretty much just Extra Utilities and Botania), and I'm wondering what the basics I need to do are. Do I just need to add the jar's to a mod folder, and MC picks them up, or is there an in between step I need too?

I currently have a Vanilla MC server running, which I have FTP access to which I can upload whatever I want, so the actual "set up a server" part I already have, and I have set up a fully modded server before (using an ATL pack).

Basically I just want to pull out the Extra Utilities and Botania mods from that server, and apply them to the (currently) Vanilla one, but I don't know what files are important and which are just for other mods I don't want.

Comment: Your question sounds like it should be titled "how do I install mods on a server" which is only one part of your "set up a server" task. There are a lot of steps to set up a server, please elaborate on what you have and what you want in the end.

Comment: @OrcJMR I've updated my post to include basically where I'm up to at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your edits, now the question looks really nice and I'm sure you'll get an answer soon :-) I personally am not familiar with those mods or ATL.

Comment: No problem. That's what happens when you rush post a question before work :P.

Comment: One thing to note though, is that if by "vanilla server" you mean an official one, this will be the first thing to sort out. Official server does not support modding, so if your mods come in the form of .jars, they are definitely designed for an aftermarket server, like CraftBukkit or Spigot. You may want to look that up first.

Comment: Ahh right, at the moment it's a Vanilla 1.8.8. server. I realised I might need to downgrade the version (most modpacks seem to be 1.7.10), but I didn't think they needed anything like that. I'll take a look later at those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a server with just a few mods, [forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net/) is an option.
If you have never worked with forge before, they have a [wiki](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/) on their site.

What you should do is create a new server with forge, this creates a custom jar. This jar file should be placed onto your server where your current minecraft file exists. After you've booted the server at least 1 time, there should be a folder named "mods".
This is the folder where you should place your mod files.

Reboot the server again to start it with these mods.

To play on the server you also need a forge client with the same mods inside it's mod folder.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I can't try this at the moment (at work) but I'll give it a try later and report back :).

Comment: Did this solution work?

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot to update. I got this all up and working locally, so porting to the server should be easy (read: do-able :P).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah actually there is a create that you can download [minecraft mods](http://www.minecraftindex.com/mods/) from and also search for them, there is literally tons of mods and just like the ones in your server some of them you can play multiplayer too!

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of how to install just a couple of mods.  The link is a place to find mods, which doesn't seem to be the problem here.  Spam?